# Yii Autoloading Custom Components

Tags: php, yii, autoload, stripe-payments

I'm trying to get Yii to autoload a component that doesn't follow Yii conventions. The library in question is [Stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/guides/php) which I moved into the Components folder. I was able to get it to autoload the main Stripe file no problem by modifying my config like this:

```
'import'=>array(
    'application.models.*',
    'application.components.*',
    'application.components.stripe.*',
),
```

The directory structure looks like:

```
Components
----------
  |
  ----> Stripe
     | 
     ----> Stripe.php    (Class Name = "Stripe")
     ----> Customer.php  (Class Name = "Stripe_Customer")
     ----> Charge.php    (Class Name = "Stripe_Charge")
     ----> etc.
```

It has no problem recognizing the `Stripe` class, but can't find the `Stripe_*` named classes. Is there a way to get Yii to recognize this pattern or am I stuck with manual `require` statements in my controller? Would it work if I renamed all the files to be what their class name is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, renaming the file to the class name would help. Otherwise you have to require the classes by yourself.

Comment: Ok thank you. So is that the "Yii Way" to have the file be named the same as the class?

Comment: Yes this is the yii way;) Though it's not a bad practice to adopt.

Answer (score 2):

You could also create your own autoloader and register it with:   `Yii::registerAutoloader(array("AutoloderClass", "methodName"), $append);`.
First parameter is actually a php callback, i used class and method notation, can be function as well. This actually calls `spl_autoload_register` in order depending on second param - before or after Yii autoloader. Autoloader should be registered in `index.php` just before `$app->run()`.

Some sample autoloader (for zend framework) can be found here:
http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/zendautoloader